Python comprehension with different number of elements
The general problem
I have a case where I'm generating an element comprehension with a different cardinality to the input source. This cardinality should not be a multiple of the original (data-driven), but rather guided by conditions. Some elements in the original source could translate to one element in the destination, whereas others might translate to more than one, or even none.
Existing approaches
Multiple questions address adjacent situations, but not quite the same:

List comprehension: Returning two (or more) items for each item [duplicate]
How can I get a flat result from a list comprehension instead of a nested list?

(By the way, I am of the view that those two questions are not duplicates of each another. They address different, if somewhat overlapping issues and although the solutions are to an extent interchangeable, the questions themselves are not.)
The first of those addresses a comprehension whose length is an exact multiple of the source's length. The second provides a way to generate flat lists from a result that had lists of lists, via reduce, or via double iteration in the comprehension itself. Note that in this case both would in fact produce an irregular number of elements (not a multiple of the original), but in a data-driven way, as opposed to a condition-driven way.
The simple problem
I have a list of strings that will either have a number or two numbers separated by a hyphen, let's say:
['1', '2', '2-3', '3-1', '4-5']

The desired outcome would be:
['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '1', '4', '5']

As you can see, no relation in cardinality (except that it grows).
Solution 1 — Lousy
>>> a = ['1', '2', '2-3', '3-1', '4-5']
>>> '-'.join(a)
'1-2-2-3-3-1-4-5'
>>> '-'.join(a).split('-')
['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '1', '4', '5']

This assumes two things:

I'm using lists. In reality, my exercise involves dictionaries, lists of tuples and such paired data collections. I could join some of these components, but I'd completely lose relationship with other parts of the source data.
This is hacky, ugly and probably inefficient.

Solution 2 — reduce
>>> a = ['1', '2', '2-3', '3-1', '4-5']
>>> reduce(lambda acc, elem: acc+elem, (x.split('-') for x in a))
['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '1', '4', '5']

This one is better than the previous one, but it's still data-driven. It is also a flattening of a list of lists, although slightly optimised by the sneaky introduction of an inner generator, instead of an inner comprehension.
The more complex problem
What if I just had a list of numbers and I wanted to generate different response lengths, depending on the values? Here, I'm moving to number lists, so that string manipulation responses are discouraged.
Now, I want a result list that puts the number if it's odd and the number and its half if it's even:
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> # Magic code
[1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]

So, depending on a condition — x % 2 == 0, in this case — I want to either add one or two numbers to the list.
Solution 0 — Missing good old C?
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> res = []
>>> for x in a:
...   if x % 2:
...     res.append(x)
...   else:
...     res.append(x//2)
...     res.append(x)
... 
>>> res
[1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]

The list of insults on this solution includes "anti-Pythonic", "ugly", etc. It works, but as I always say: "If 'it works' is the best / only good thing you can say about your code..."
Solution 1 — Multi-dimensional list flattening
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [x if x % 2 else [x//2, x] for x in a]
[1, [1, 2], 3, [2, 4], 5]

Now I have a list with both elements and lists. My reduce would be a bit more complex, so I'm going to make them all lists:
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [[x] if x % 2 else [x//2, x] for x in a]
[[1], [1, 2], [3], [2, 4], [5]]

Now I can reduce:
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> reduce(lambda acc, elem: acc+elem, ([x] if x % 2 else [x//2, x] for x in a))
[1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]

Once again, works but not directly. It still creates an iterable to reduce.
I need a solution that simply feeds the target with a variable number of elements calculated from each source element. The reason why this must be expression-like is that this is embedded in a wider expression. So, despite my huge respect for them, no Kernighan&Ritchie imperative solutions, please.
Edit
Some contributors mentioned that I was "willing to use reduce". I tried to make it obvious that I was looking for something different. I love reduce and all things functional, but its resource usage is only justifiable when data comes in "as is".
As for readability and the imperative for, nothing against it. I work the whole day in Python and C. It's just that for is more about "how", whereas comprehensions are more about "what". I guess readability is ultimately a matter of preference:
Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
...

Some commenters mentioned "real world", "production-ready" and "readability". To those, I recommend reading the source code of some libraries that you use every day. I do and it's a great exercise. You should also try PDB and checking things like code length, memoty usage, etc.
I'd like to leave a special mention and thank you to jsbueno. You make valid points. yield rocks and it's part of my personal toolchain for performance, for "Pythonicity" is only my #2 goal.
Another thank you goes for Dogbert. Your suggestion was what I think is the way to go. I must confess I had the solution already when I posted this, and the difference between yours and mine is just square vs. round.
For the rest, if the approach is "as long as it works", then I guess lots of questions are duplicates and yes, the way from Cambridge to London can go via Honolulu, "as long as we get there".
I abused the term "Pythonic", not even being 100% sure what it means. I was trying to not use libraries and keep it "native".
Here's my solution:
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [ x for i in a for x in ((i,) if i % 2 else (i // 2, i)) ]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]

One line.

I think you're looking for the function commonly known as flatMap/concatMap in other languages. Python does not have one built in AFAIK but you can use a nested for comprehension: xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; [y for x in xs for y in ([x] if x % 2 else [x // 2, x])].

Your question has a lot of moving parts, and as a result, I think you're actually asking about two different problems. Your simple and complex cases may have some things in common, but I still think they're different and each deserve their own posts.

You call solution 1 lousy and inefficient and call solution 2 better?

actually, the "one obvious way" of doing it, and more Pythonic approach is what you call "Solution 0"
Comprehensions in Python are syntactic constructions to improve expressivenes, keep the code dense so that less lines of code contain more obvious operations taking place.
It is in no way "recommend", "mandatory"  and "code not using comprehensions is not Pythonic". To the contrary, "readability counts" - and any way out you get there will not be more readable than the multi-line, full if-blocks version. What you wnt to achieve tastes more like code-golfing than anything actually "needed"

And I don't man the question is not good, and worth pursuing - please. It will be a fun solution to come across with. It is just that it won't be more "Pythonic".

This looks like a golf-like question. The restriction that it should work inside an expression is rather meaningless since you seem ready to use functions from libraries, like reduce, so that means you could still write an imperative style function, and have it called from within the expression you refer to.

As already pointed out, the required solution is a "flatmap". Since an implementation of this is given in one of your linked questions, and the two answers you have are simply variations on the same theme, I have closed this as a duplicate. (PS: another variation would be: def iflatmap(func, i): for x in map(func, i): yield from x).

"This was meant as a brain teaser"—please take the [tour]. Stack Overflow is for real, practical programming questions. I'm sure that there are places online for brain teasers, but this isn't one of them. We ask for a [mre] for a reason: to quickly and directly get to an answer. See also [ask], which says in part "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague".

@Chris What do you mean with brain teaser?

@nocomment, that language was a quote from OP's latest edit. Brain teasers are games. They often involve contrived examples and tricks. That conflicts with our usage guidelines: we ask people to post questions here as clearly as possible. SO is for getting answers and building a library of existing questions and answers to help other users in the future. Brain teasers aren't compatible with that.

@Chris I know they said it first, I wondered what you meant because you said this is not a place for them. Still not entirely sure. Some of my most successful questions are what the OP or you might consider brain teasers. Things that I knew and decided to share in the form of a question, leaving answering to others because I think that's better. I guess mine were just better (I do try hard to make them as concise as I can, for example).

@nocomment, self-answers are fine and maybe that's what OP meant by "brain teaser". There's nothing wrong with sharing something you already know as long as it fits the question-and-answer format and the question is on-topic. The wordy nature of this question makes me think that's not what OP had in mind… In any case, true brain teasers, where things are deliberately obfuscated, aren't what we want here. There are other places for games, code golf, etc. (OP's edited-into-the-question answer proudly says that it's "one line", so maybe golf is what they're going for.) On SO, we prefer clarity.

Hi Ricardo. Now that this question is open again, could you move the answer to the answer space?

Either reduce or itertools.chain.from_iterable will flatten any "sequency" elements - so that is, semantically, the way to go on the outer level. Although the reduce approach will consume all data eagerly, create N intermediate lists, as + for lists is not inplace, and ultimately have poor performance.
And in the inner generator, you just have to ensure each element is a sequence (I think chain.from_iterable can work with an arbitrary iterable), containing all elements you choose - even if it is one. I guess that would be generic enough.
For example, a different example: each number should be replaced by "self" occurences of itself:
In [9]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([i] * i for i in [1,2,3,4,5] ))
Out[9]: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]


or, for rules that are more complex, like the one you give, just keep adding terms in the "expression" part of the inner generator, and use the inline if ... else  to select whether they should be added:
In [13]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable (
    ([v // 2] if not v % 2 else []) + 
     [v] 
     for v in [1,2,3,4,5]
    ))
Out[13]: [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]


but really, don't!
As I've put in the comments, if comprehensions will be harder to read (and much harder to write)  than the "extended code", in "real World" projects, the multi-line formula should be preferred.
One of the strong points of Python across the years had been to invite code to be easy to read. Eventually the language grew so much it no longer holds, nonetheless, using a function rather than a generator will make your code-reviewers, and code base users or sucessors thank you:
def expand_even(x: Iterable) -> Iterable:
    for i in x:
        if not i % 2:
            yield i // 2
        yield i
 

And:
In [17]: list(expand_even([1,2,3,4,5]))
Out[17]: [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]


Can hardly be said to be worth of a "list of insults".
(still, even in this example, there is a pattern you might like in your original "Pythonicity" quest - by using a full generator function, it is just a matter of using one yield in the code for each element the original input should expand into (or none if it is to be suppressed))

I wouldn't call their reduce way "the way to go",  as it leads to quadratic runtime.

and is also eager vs lazy.  really, "the way to go"  is to have a muli-line generator function as written last in the answer.

Here's another solution
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = ['1', '2', '2-3', '3-1', '4-5']
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(item.split('-') for item in a))
['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '1', '4', '5']


What you are looking for is a flat_map in functional programming, that essentially maps a function f onto an Iterable and then flatterns the results.
A generic flat_map can be defined as follows:
(I've added type hints for brevity)
from itertools import chain
from typing import TypeVar, Iterable, Callable

A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B')
Fn = Callable[A, Iterable[B]]

def flat_map(f: Fn, xs: Iterable[A]) -> Iterable[B]:
    return chain.from_iterable(map(f, xs))

Now, you can use it for any custom Iterable and function.
Example:
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
f = lambda x: (x,) if x % 2 else (x // 2, x)
ys = flat_map(f, xs)
assert list(ys) == [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5]

xs = ['1', '2', '2-3', '3-1', '4-5']
f = lambda x: x.split('-')
ys = flat_map(f, xs)
assert list(ys) == ['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '1', '4', '5']

And, of course, if this is too verbose, you can always use the 1-liners, similar to what you mentioned.
xs = ['1', '2', '2-3', '3-1', '4-5']
ys = chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: x.split('-'), xs))
zs = chain.from_iterable([x.split('-') for x in xs])
assert list(ys) == list(zs) == ['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '1', '4', '5']

